# Python paramiko zimbra

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente con paramiko en python y no me funciona:

```
import paramiko
Conexion = paramiko.SSHClient ()
Conexion.set_missing_host_key_policy (paramiko.AutoAddPolicy ())
Conexion.connect (Servidor, Puerto, Usuario, Password)
Conexion.exec_command ('su zimbra') //crea un subshell para zimbra
Stdin, Stdout, Stderr = Conexion.exec_command ('zmprov ga usuario@dominio.com') //mostrar detalles de ese usuario en zimbra
print (Stdrer.readlines ())
```

¿Por qué me retorna `bash: zmprov: command not found`? ¿Cómo hago para ejecutar comandos sobre el subshell de zimbra? Saludos.

Comment: Puede ser un problema de path. Prueba a ejecutarlo con el path completo.

Comment: Ya probé y hace lo mismo.

Comment: El comando "su" lee la password desde el teclado. ¿Te funciona "su zimbra" desde el teclado?

Comment: Si, funciona perfecto. Lo que quiero es lanzar comandos sobre el propio zimbra.

Comment: He visto que se puede guardar el stdin de ejecutar 'su zimbra'. Sobre ese stdin se ejecuta write y al final se ejecuta flush. No se ve muy elegante, pero aun no he probado si funciona.